# Spin and Symmetry of SM Particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, gauge-invariance

I am reading about Quantum Field theory and I cannot understand how do physicists assign spin to particles. Is there a systematic way to assign spin to particles without knowing it first through experiments? In a book from which I learn QFT there has been given no reason for why Weak and Strong forces are spin $1$ particles. To my knowledge spins are assigned by trial and error. For example the graviton. First it was thought to be a spin $0$ field. Since a spin $0$ field did not react to relativistic matter, it had to be wrong. Obviously it can't be spin $1$ because then matter will repel. Then we tried spin $2$ and it worked. (Also general relativity predicts the wave to have a helicity of $2$, but that's not point.) So was procedure carried out for every particle?

Similarly I have no idea how a symmetry group is assigned to a theory. Why QED follows $U(1)$ symmetry while QCD follows $SU(3)$ symmetry? Again is there a systematic way to prove that a theory will follow a certain symmetry group?

Also I am new to QFT so excuse me if my question is totally ridiculous.

Comment: You added the tag “gauge invariance”. Gauge invariance requires photons, gluons, and W and Z bosons to have spin 1.

Comment: @G.Smith To my knowledge there is also a gauge relation for spin-2 field. $$h_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow h_{\mu\nu} + \partial_{\mu}\epsilon_{\nu} + \partial_{\nu}\epsilon_{\mu}$$ where $x^{\mu}\rightarrow x^{\mu} + \epsilon^{\mu}$. Which does it follow? How do we know? Also I might be wrong.

Comment: Yes, gravity can also be considered a gauge theory, but a different kind of one from the electroweak and strong interactions. In gravity the gauge involves spacetime itself, whereas in the others the gauge symmetry is “internal” and operates on quantum fields.

Comment: QED follows U(1), not SU(2).

Comment: @G.Smith oh, thanks.

Comment: We *discover*, rather than *prove*, which symmetry group is related to which force. However, there are certain constraints. For example, photons do not directly interact with photons, so if EM has a gauge symmetry it must be abelian.

Comment: It is somewhat miraculous that the three forces of the Standard Model have as their gauge groups three of the simplest possible Lie groups.

Comment: @G.Smith Also a follow up question, which group is quantum gravity said to follow?

Comment: @G.Smith Is it really a coincidence or is there some deeper reason for this?

Comment: There are a variety of quite different theories of quantum gravity. We don’t understand why the three SM forces have rather simple Lie groups. The site is telling me to avoid extended discussions in chat, so I will stop now.